# Избавиться от повторяемости кода

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++

Имею следующий код. Хотел бы избавиться от повторяемости. По сути все дубляжи друг от друга отличаются только типами `Header, Code, NumberedList, MarkedList`. Первая мысль - создать коллекцию типов (именно типов, не объектов), и пройтись по ней циклом, а в теле цикла записать блок `try`. Но, кажется, в `c++` это невозможно. Что я могу сделать? Спасибо

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ParagraphFactory.h"
#include "StringUtils.h"
#include "Code.h"
#include "NumberedList.h"
#include "MarkedList.h"

Paragraph* ParagraphFactory::Create(const wchar_t* const text, OutputConfig config)
{
    Paragraph* result = nullptr;
    
    try
    {
        result = Paragraph::Create<Header>(text, config);
        return result;
    }
    catch (int e)
    {

    }

    try
    {
        result = Paragraph::Create<Code>(text, config);
        return result;
    }
    catch (int e)
    {

    }

    try
    {
        result = Paragraph::Create<NumberedList>(text, config);
        return result;
    }
    catch (int e)
    {

    }

    try
    {
        result = Paragraph::Create<MarkedList>(text, config);
        return result;
    }
    catch (int e)
    {

    }

    throw 0;
}
```

Comment: а нужны именно шаблоны, или старый простой макрос сойдет?

Comment: Создайте массив указателей на функции. `{ Paragraph::Create<Header>,  Paragraph::Create<Code>, ... `